debugging a script using vscode / debugging in a remote server [fixed]
For the first time, i installed vscode in my laptop to work on a remote server (tradtionaly i'm using spyder when i'm working locally). I'm facing difficulties to debbug python codes in the distant server.

Question 1: where is the right place for the launch.json file:


the in user/.vscode folder (my laptop here)?
or in the working/.vscode directory (the remote server in that case)?


Question 2: how to correctly run the debugger to use its toolbar (ctrl+shift+D):


as described in the doc, the ssh tunnel is opened: ssh -2 -L 5678:localhost:5678 user@remoteserver
the launch.json file has been updated with the new configuration (see after)
note the pathMappings is still unclear for me (vscode points on the remote server and files, do i need a local copy?)
now i'm trying to start debugging with Ctrl+Shift+D (not in command line to take advantages of the debugging toolbar; i've been using the "Python: Debugger: Attach"

I tried on a basic python file but it do not work: what i'm missing?
```{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python Debugger: Attach",
        "type": "debugpy",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5678,
        "host": "localhost",
        "pathMappings": [
            {
                "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "remoteRoot": "."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Python Debugger: Python File",
        "type": "debugpy",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}"
    }
]

} ```

Question 3: how to run a script?

Python codes are launched using a script because i need to provide an argument (json file name):

python myScript.py --file=f.json
i know a debugger runs on a python file and not a script but how to proceed? is there a vscode extension to use?

Thanks for advice(s) on each topic
Paul

Are you using the "Remote Development" set of plugins from Microsoft here?

@JonSG: depends of what you are saying by "remote development set" ... so far i've installed "Remote SSH - Remote SSH editing configuration files - Remote tunnels and Remote explorer"

So, I would expect you to be able to click on the little blue icon on the lower left of the gui and choose "Connect to Host" and provide your info/credentials. At that point, your experience (files/edits/shell/debugging) should all more on the remote host, though you can crick and drag local files into the remote directory if you liked.

to debug with arguments you can "add a config"  for example "Python Debugger: Current File with Arguments"

Now i'm able to debug locally and remotly a python file (including arguments). Now i would like to add an additional difficulty by loading specific variables environements: "module load", "export path & ld_library", "source env" for instance.
Except if i'm wrong, i guess i need to define a local .env file in which all previous variables are declared: is it correct? i've also added an additional argument in the launch.json file using:
"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"

Is it the right way?
(nontheless it does not work for me, so i'm looking where i've made a mistake or if i've mussed something)
Any feedback is highly appreciated
Paul
